# Em JS como eu faco para listar o conteudo de um "objeto" ou "array"?

Tags: javascript

Tenho esse objeto desconhecido e preciso trabalhar com ele, entao tentei usar o console:

```
console.log('01 =', this);
```

mas so me retorna um `"01 = Object { length: 1, 1 more… }"`

Como fazer isso? ou...  o que seria o equivalente ao "print_r" do php?

obrigado!

**ps**: um detalhe que nao entendi bem... eh que aquele "**1 more…** "  ali no resultado....  pode ser clicado, e o mozilla... exibe uma informacao gigante sobre infos da pagina...  mas **nao achei nada** sobre variaveis ou informacoes dos meus dados..

Answer (score -1):

Tente isso:

console.log('índice:' + i);
console.log(this);

Comment: A primeira linha coloquei para representar o índice de um for, caso não tenha coloque apenas está linha:console.log(this);

Comment: Nao sei se estou falando besteira...  mas parece exatamente com o codigo que citei  na perguinta... nao?